How to construct a DPDA for a $\{x\#y \mid x \in L \land xy \in L\}$ when $L$ is a DCFL
Assume $L$ is accepted by a deterministic pushdown automaton (DPDA) $P = (Q, \Sigma, \Gamma, \delta, q_0, Z_0, F)$. I want to construct a DPDA that accepts the following language:
$$ \{x\#y \mid x \in L \land xy \in L\} $$
where $\#$ is a special symbol not present in any string of $L$.
My initial idea was to use two copies of $P$, denoted as $P^1$ and $P^2$. States $q \in Q$ in $P^1$ are represented as $q^1$, and in $P^2$ as $q^2$. I planned to do the following:

For every final state $q_f^1$ in $P^1$ and every $X \in \Gamma$, add a transition
$$ \delta^1(q_f^1, \#, X) = (q_f^2, X). $$
This means that when $P^1$ reaches a final state and reads $\#$, it transitions to the corresponding state in $P^2$, carrying over the stack.

Make the final states of $P^1$ non-final, leaving only $P^2$'s final states as the accepting states of the new DPDA.


However, there's a problem:
This approach may violate the determinism of the resulting PDA. If $\delta^1(q_f^1, \epsilon, X)$ is nonempty, adding the new transition
$$ \delta^1(q_f^1, \#, X) = (q_f^2, X) $$
introduces nondeterminism.
I've tried similar ideas, but I couldn't ensure the resulting PDA remains deterministic. Can anyone suggest a way to construct the desired DPDA or resolve this issue?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Seems you are very close. My suggestion is to insert yet another copy of $P$ in between the first and second phase. That copy will only read $\varepsilon$'s. At the moment it is ready to read a symbol $a$ (given state and stack) you will make it read $\#$ and move to the last phase where it will continue waith $a$.
Here I assume that $y$ is nonempty, so it will indeed encounter a next letter.
(Disclaimer: I did not check all details.)

I’m having trouble understanding how the transitions for the middle copy should be constructed—specifically, the moves from the first copy to the second, the moves from the second copy to the third, and the transitions within the second copy itself. Could you provide more details or clarification on this?
